# Building generic overloaded operator<<

Tags: c++, templates

How can we make a generic overloaded operator<< ?

I wrote this code but clearly it has errors - missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

```
class b{
private:
    int i;
public:
    b(){}
    b(const int& ii):i(ii){}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const t& obj);//Error here
};


class a:public b{
private:
    int i;
    int x;
public:
    a(){}
    a(const int& ii,const int& xx):i(ii),x(xx){}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const t& obj);//Error here
};

template<class t>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const t& obj){
         o<<obj.i;
         return o;
}

int main()
 {
    b b1(9); 
    a a1(8,6);
    cout<<a1<<endl<<b1;
    _getch();
 }
```

What can be done here?

Edit: Changed "int i" to a private member

Answer:
friend function needs to be declared this way in class a and class b:

```
template<class t>
    friend ostream& operator<< <>(ostream& o,const t& obj);
```

Comment: Pass the template arg since you've made it a template function. Not sure about this design however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `template<class t>` into the `friend` declaration as well.

I wouldn't design `operator<<` this way, however - why would it need access to private members? Better add a getter for `i` to both `a` and `b` and avoid the socializing stuff altogether.

**Edit** In the given code the `friend` declarations would not even be required as `i` is `public` in both cases. I based my answer on the presumption that they are intended to be `private` because otherwise being friends makes no sense here.

Comment: It was more of a learning exercise...loved the comment though "Socializing Stuff" :D:D

Comment: True!! careless programming i would say... :(

Answer (score 1):

What's a `t`?  In the template itself it represents an arbitrary type, but that's after the two uses of it that are causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function like

```
template<class t>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const t& value)
```

You must at least put this in the same namespace as the types you want to print. Otherwise, the type `t` will match **all types** in the entire program, including all my types that I perhaps don't want to print this way.

It is generally not a good idea to define a template for any `t` as you risk making it way too general. Ask yourself, will it really work for **all** `t`s?